# Why .NET use the generic logger?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, logging

Using Microsoft's default setup, the logger is injected using `ILogger<Worker>` like so (directly from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line))

```
public sealed class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger) =>
        _logger = logger;

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
            await Task.Delay(1_000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

What benefit does this pattern provides, (apart from the logger's name I think) against using directly `ILogger`? - or what do we lose, using the `ILogger` without the generic part `ILogger<Worker>`

I believe there are some slight differences and disagreements that are not resolved yet here https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48473
but are there even more?

Comment: This is an assumption based on my experience with Serilog: it might create a context for you log message, so it logs in the structured log message the class name as well.

Comment: Have you read through the whole document, or just stopped at this example? Because the sections on filtering and the bit "`ILogger<T>` is equivalent to calling `CreateLogger` with the fully qualified type name of `T`." basically cover why this convention exists.

Comment: ^^ I'd also assume it may be about categories.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I believe I have included that knowledge for logger name in the question. I am asking what is beyond that though

Comment: you can use scoping or filtering based on the ILogger<T> i dont think this works with the non generic ILogger.

Comment: "apart from the logger's name I think" yes, exactly that. And because in dependency injection, each `Type` can only have one implementation `Type`, using a generic parameter solves both the log name and integrates well with the DI `Type` system at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

`ILogger` is a historical interface used by Microsoft and other third parties logging libraries (such as Serilog) to abstract the logger, preventing devloppers from coupling their application code to a single library. This allows application developpers to change their logging library if needed.

`ILogger<T>` inherits from `ILogger` and is Microsoft's new abstraction of a logger. The generic prevents collisions in the DI engine. Also note that starting from .NET 6, [Microsoft's logging library does not register the `ILogger` anymore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line). This means you *need* to inject an `ILogger<T>` into your services.

Other libraries may not have made the update yet, and you might still *need* to inject `ILogger` objects for them to work. See your library documentation. If you need compatibility, you may register the `ILogger` manually and continue to use an `ILogger` in the injection.

Also note that you can drop the generic part after injection:

```cs
public sealed class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger) => _logger = logger; // implicit cast

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
            await Task.Delay(1_000, stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An answer to your question can be found in the documentation itself: the very last line under the heading [Log Category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#log-category). Copying from there:

> `ILogger<T>` is equivalent to calling `CreateLogger` with the fully qualified type name of `T`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot inject `ILogger` directly through the ctor with the standard MS DI method, there is a way you can do it.

Just add the [EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac) nuget package to your startup project and modify your `Program.cs` file as below:

```cs
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder
    .Host
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(
        containerBuilder =>
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac.DependencyModule>();
    );
```

You can keep your existing dependency registrations using MS DI methods, they will be resolved by the `AutofacServiceProvider` instead of `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider`. Both implement the same `IServiceProvider` interface.

Now you can inject `ILogger` instead of `ILogger<T>`.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Service
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public Service(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Of course, you may ask, if it is worth adding a nuget package for this.

MS DI methods may cover the basic use cases, but Autofac has solutions for advanced use cases.

E.g. the module registered in the example code adds a custom middleware into the Autofac's resolve pipeline. This middleware simply extends the parameter list by an additional parameter so that when an `ILogger` parameter needs to be resolved then it resolves the generic `ILogger<>` type with the declaring type of the parameter. See [here](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.Autofac/blob/main/src/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.Logging.AutofacV6/DependencyModule.cs).

**Please note:**

You still won't be able to resolve an `ILogger` instance directly with the extension methods for `IServiceProvider`, e.g. `GetService<T>()` or `GetRequiredService<T>()`. Instead, you can use `ILoggerFactory.CreateLogger(string)` method.

**Alternatively,** you can inject an `ILoggerFactory` into the ctor and create the logger there.

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public class Service
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public Service(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(GetType());
    }
}
```